# Custom superbar shortcut icons missing after restart

Tags: windows-8, taskbar, icons

I want to add web-app shortcuts to my Windows 8 superbar.

Here's what I did:

1. Created a shortcut (`.lnk`)
2. Pointing to an URL (e.g. `https://gmail.com/`)
3. Changed the icon to a custom, pretty `.ico` file
4. Pinned it to the taskbar

The results, at first, were quite satisfying:

[image: Custom icons]

But after a restart, this happens:

[image: Blank icons]

Notes:

- Rebuilding the icon cache didn't work
- Logging out doesn't affect the icons, only shutting down / restarting does
- The `.lnk` files, as well as the `.ico` files, are saved and not moved (so they should be found)

What can I do to fix this?

Edit: To specify, the clover icon is not a web app, it's [Clover](http://ejie.me/).

Edit 2: Seeing the lack of answers, can anyone even reproduce this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I have web apps pinned to my taskbar and that doesn't happen. I never used your approach of creating links, i just create them with google chrome:

Step 1:

[image]

Step 2:

[image]

And it gets pinned to the taskbar and are then used as standalone apps.

And if you want to change the icons to your custom icons, you can do that also, by right clicking the button and then right clicking again on the application name and select "Properties". You might need to reboot your computer to make them appear.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not trying to create Chrome application shortcuts. These open in separate windows, without tabs or the address bar, which makes them unpractical to me. I want to create plain old URL shortcuts that will open in my default browser (Chrome, in this case).

Comment: If you don't want them to open in a separate window, just remove the `--app=` part from the target of the shortcut. They will start opening in a chrome window.